# Any publicly available word dictionary in a text file?

Tags: dictionary, nlp

I am looking for a word dictionary for different languages(english, spanish, ...). However, almost all dictionaries that I could find are either provided by a program or on a website.

I want to get this word dictionary as a text file. (Also, this file should be publicly available.) Are there any public available word dictionaries in text files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the Wikitionary for off-line processing, instructions here in the FAQ:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Help:FAQ#Downloading_Wiktionary

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Linux user, you can use one of the following files (depending on your distribution)

- /usr/share/dict/
- /var/lib/dict/

The GNU 'aspell' program makes use of this [dictionary](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/en/aspell5-en-6.0-0.tar.bz2).

Comment: I though about that, but my interpretation was that he/she wanted a dictionary with word definitions, not just only words.